# ItextSharp : How to set dynamic header using ITextsharp. C#.Net

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating PDF with 3 pages, all 3 pages should have 3 different headers. I came across one example in documentation  [VaraibleHeader.](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers#693-variableheader.java)  However its not working below is my code.

```
  public class ReportPdfHeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
  {
        public void SetHeader(string header)
        {
            this._header = header;
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.AddCell(title);
            footer.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, Pdf.MarginLeft, document.Bottom, writer.DirectContent);
         }
   }

  public CreatePdf()
  {
       private Document _doc;
       private MemoryStream _memStream;
       private PdfWriter _pdfWriter;
       this._doc = new Document();
       this._memStream = new MemoryStream();
       this._pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(this._doc, _memStream);
       var reportPdfHeaderFooter = new ReportPdfHeaderFooter();

       _pdfWriter.PageEvent = headerFooter;
       reportPdfHeaderFooter.SetHeader("Header 1");
       _doc.Open();
       reportPdfHeaderFooter.SetHeader("Header 2");
       _doc.NewPage();
       _doc.Close();
 }
```

I have done exactly whatever mentioned in the documentation, still i am getting Header 2 as title in both the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it looks like you're on the right track, must be a bad copy/paste for your `ReportPdfHeaderFooter` class above, which won't compile as-is.

Here's a simple working example to get you started.

First the `PdfPageEventHelper` implementation:

```
public class PageEventHeader : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        float cellHeight = document.TopMargin;
        Rectangle page = document.PageSize;
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1) { TotalWidth = page.Width };
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(HeaderText)) 
        { 
            Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,
            FixedHeight = cellHeight,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        });
        table.WriteSelectedRows(
            0, -1, 0,
            page.Height - cellHeight + table.TotalHeight,
            writer.DirectContent
        );
    }
}
```

Second, the test PDF file creation:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var header = new PageEventHeader();
    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();

        writer.PageEvent = header;
        header.HeaderText = "Header 0";
        document.Add(new Phrase("Header 0"));
        document.NewPage();
        header.HeaderText = "Header 1";
        document.Add(new Phrase("Header 1"));
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(OUTPUT_FILE, stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still not getting two headers. Both the pages are displaying Header 1

Comment: @ManishMakkad - not sure what to say. I always test code before providing **any** answers. The code above correctly sets different header text on each page. You might want to edit your question with the **exact** code you're using. Again, the code example you provided is incomplete, as it won't compile. For example, `ReportPdfHeaderFooter.OnEndPage()` has a variable named `footer`, which is never declared/defined.

Comment: I had posted half code snippets, i found out the issue thanks :)